# basic auth through the url

Tags: curl, browser, basic-authentication

I am learning how to write a rest api and I can curl to it from the command line and get the expected response with the following line

```
curl -v -u username:pass -X GET http://api.mysite.com/user/1
```

But when I try to access it through the browser the username and password for the basic auth are not being received by my api.  This is not working for me

```
http://username:pass@api.mysite.com/user/1
```

I know my api is not getting the username and password because I check the $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and it is blank.

Why am I receiving the credentials through curl but not through the browser?

Comment: help http://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: This way of passing credentials has never been “official” for HTTP URLs, and while browsers used to support it earlier, that has been changed a few years back, for security concerns. Today some browsers allow it only after asking the user if he rely wants to send those credentials, and others allow it only when it is explicitly set in their config. (IIRC for IE it even needs a registry entry.)

Comment: Any idea on how to do it with Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass credentials in URL, this method is deprecated in many modern browsers for security reasons, it's never been official either. If you are looking for a more convenient way of developing/testing/working with your API I could recommend installing this extension for Chrome: [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en)

Then just set `Authorization` HTTP header properly. Wikipedia is your friend answering how to do this: [Basic Access Authentication - Client side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side)